# Configuration for Mvc testing

Tags: spring-mvc-test

guys. I have spring MVC project and I want to test CoursesController, but can not find out how to do it.
Do I need to make separated configuration class for tests?

Before springMvc I used separated configuration class for test with embedded database.

I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

CoursesController class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/courses")
public class CoursesController {
    
    private final CourseService courseService;

    @Autowired
    public CoursesController(CourseService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model, @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page,
                @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> size) throws ServiceException {
        int currentPage = page.orElse(1);
        int pageSize = size.orElse(10);

        Page<Course> coursePage = courseService.findPaginated(PageRequest.of(currentPage - 1, pageSize));

        model.addAttribute("coursePage", coursePage);

        int totalPages = coursePage.getTotalPages();
        if (totalPages > 0) {
            List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
        }

        return "courses/index";
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.university")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public Config(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"))
                .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
              templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did separate configuration class for tests with H2 database.